# Xcode 6.4 - Autocomplete Doesn't Show Type Symbols

Tags: xcode

My Xcode has suddenly stopped showing the symbols that shows what type each suggestion is. Here is what it looks like:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this: close your project and your Xcode;
Right click on the project and select the Show Package Contents, then open xcuserdata folder and delete the [username].xcuserdata folder.
Open the Xcode, clean your project and build it once for device (not for simulator).
It worked for me.