# Xcode 6.4 autocomplete for my class not working?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

1. I change the search for user path to yes
2. Delete the contents of the DerivedData folder (`~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`)
3. I restart Xcode   but autocomplete didn't call my class proprety

Comment: Are you mixing Swift and Objective-C?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 6.4 - Autocomplete Doesn't Show Type Symbols](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528793/xcode-6-4-autocomplete-doesnt-show-type-symbols)

Answer (score 1):

Try this: close your project and your Xcode;
Right click on the project and select the Show Package Contents, then open xcuserdata folder and delete the [username].xcuserdata folder.
Open the Xcode, clean your project and build it once for device (not for simulator).
It worked for me.